# How does gitolite map a remote user to a repository user ?

Tags: ssh, key, public, gitolite

---

How does gitolite map a remote user accessing git via gitolite  to a  gitolite user (repo user) ?.Is  this from the **public key file name** in keydir ?. Is  it mandatory to name 
the public-key file as  **username.pub** . 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is the *name* of the public key registered in the `gitolite-admin` repo which is used as a parameter in the `~git/.ssh/authorized-keys` file (generated by gitolite when detecting new users on a push of the `gitolite-admin` repo)

That  `~git/.ssh/authorized-keys`  will call gitolite-shell on each ssh call, if said call is done with a user public ssh key registered in that file.
That call to `gitolite-shell` will be done with the username as a parameter.

See for more "[how gitolite uses ssh](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/glssh.html)".

> Restricting users to specific commands is very important for gitolite.
>   If you read **[`man sshd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd)** and look for `authorized_keys` file format, you'll see a lot of options you can add to the public key line, which restrict the incoming user in various ways.
>   In particular, note the `command=` option, which means "regardless of what the incoming user is asking to do, forcibly run this command instead".
>
> Also note that when there are many public keys (i.e., lines) in the authorized_keys file, each line can have a different set of options and command= values.
>
> Without this command= option, the ssh daemon will simply give you a shell, which is not what we want for our gitolite keys (although we may well have other keys which we use to get a shell).

Note: that `command=` mechanism is an [**ssh forced-command**](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#22858).

[image: forced command in ssh]

> **This is the backbone of what makes gitolite work; please make sure you understand this.**
>
> If you look in the authorized_keys file, you'll see entries like this (I chopped off the ends of course; they're pretty long lines):

```
command="[path]/gitolite-shell sitaram",[more options] ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA18S2t...
command="[path]/gitolite-shell usertwo",[more options] ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEArXtCT...
```

> First, it finds out which of the public keys in this file match the incoming login.
>   Once the match has been found, it will run the command given on that line; e.g., if I logged in, it would run `[path]/gitolite-shell sitaram`.
>   So the first thing to note is that such users do not get "shell access", which is good!
>
> Before running the command, however, sshd sets up an environment variable called `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` which contains the actual git command that your workstation sent out.
>   This is the command that would have run if you did not have the `command=` part in the authorised keys file.

When `gitolite-shell` gets control, it looks at the first argument ("`sitaram`", "`usertwo`", etc) to determine who you are. It then looks at the `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` variable to find out which repository you want to access, and whether you're reading or writing.

Comment: Crsytal clear , Thanks VonC , I will go through sshd man page.